# Auto login with PHP facebook connect + JS

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, autologin

since all the changes facebook made in the past year lot of things are changed.
there are some solutions over the web but they do not work any more.
(LIKE THIS ONE: [Using the PHP or JavaScript Facebook SDK, how can I keep the user logged in to my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135474/using-the-php-or-javascript-facebook-sdk-how-can-i-keep-the-user-logged-in-to-m/11611015#comment15398973_11611015))

I have implemented facebook connect with PHP facebook SDK on my website.
the problem is with users that already approved my App and that also logged in to their facebook.
In this case I want them the auto login with no need to press the connect button again.
I guess that there is a way to do it using php+js but I couldn't find how and believe me I tried several things. the problem is that the php user check

```
$user  = $facebook->getUser();
```

doesn't recognized facebook session and I think that maybe I can trigger it with JS.
so I tired adding this code for the page in JS and the ALRETS are working saying user is connected but NO session pass to PHP, so PHP SDK doesn't recognize user is connected :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
              appId  : '<?=FACEBOOK_APP_ID?>',
              status : true, // 
              cookie : true, // 
              xfbml  : true, //
              oauth  : true
        });

      // Additional initialization code here
 //--------> this isn't need to work its only a check
FB.getLoginStatus( function(response) {
    //console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        alert(accessToken);
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        //login function
    } else {
        //login function
    }
}, true);

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    //console.log('The status of the session changed to: '+response.status);
    alert(response.status);
});

 //--------> END OF CHECK!!
      };
      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/<?=$fb_api_lang?>/all.js#xfbml=1";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));
    </script>
```

if anyone found a solution for this problem and could share it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the problem is that the php user check `$user  = $facebook->getUser();` doesn't recognized facebook session

Well of course it *can’t* – because server-side it can only access the cookies set for your domain. But Facebook can not set a cookie for your domain without the user being on that domain and interacting with Facebook.

> and I think that maybe I can trigger it with JS.

Just embed the JavaScript SDK, initialize it and set the `cookie: true` parameter. That will make the JS SDK set a cookie under your domain, which PHP can read *on the next request*.

If you want to recognize a returning user “immediately”, then you would have to check client-side for this, and reload your page once when the appropriate conditions are met: JS SDK recognized returning user (`FB.getLoginStatus`), but PHP did not recognize him yet (have your PHP code set a variable/flag, that your JS can evaluate) – then reload page via JS, so that PHP can read the cookie that was just set by the client-side JS.

Comment: I tried what you're saying something like that but it isn't working-
    ` <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
 appId  : '<?=FACEBOOK_APP_ID?>',
 status : true,
 cookie : true, 
 xfbml  : true,
 oauth  : true
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected') {
var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
window.location.refresh(true);
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
  } else {

  }
 });
    };
  </script> `

Comment: Could you add that code as an edit to your original question for better readability? Thanks!

Comment: Done, Have a look. :\ (BTW Thank you)

Comment: So, does PHP recognize the user after a reload or going to some other link inside the app? If yes, then you just have to add an automatic reload via JavaScript on first load, if you want the user to be known from the start. If not, then you’re most likely having a cookie problem. (Keyword: _Third Party Cookies_)

Comment: as you can see I changed the current JS script to show alerts with Token and to say that user connected.after a check it is connected using the JS SDK and shows the alerts of connected and Token as shown in the code. but PHP doesn't recognize it after manual reload or JS window reload.

Comment: Then, _as I said_, you’re most likely experiencing the old _thrid party cookies_ problem …

Comment: is it a server Third Party Cookies problem ? (since my browser is approving third Party Cookies) some specific solution reference will really help here...

Comment: Well, if your browser accepts third party cookies – then do a debug output of what cookies your server-side script actually receives.

Comment: I believe that JS sdk send the regular cookie and it works fine, it's just that the PHP sdk refuse to get the user session or use this JS cookie. how can I check that? or maybe I need some special php code for checking this JS cookie. Do you know sites that use PHP sdk and JS that will auto login?

Comment: Yes, I have that combination working, and I am not experiencing any problems of that sort. Are you using the latest version of the PHP SDK? You don’t need any special code, the SDK is capable of taking care of all that’s necessary by itself.

Comment: YOU WERE RIGHT... I needed to update the base file in the SDK. so after I updated the SDK - problem solved! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you performing proper:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
));
```

before calling this method? Are you using same domain?

Comment: YES ... (and the login is working perfect it's just that auto login doesn't work and user that left the website for a long period will have to click connect again)