# Auto login to facebook using php sdk

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Am working on facebook application using php sdk to post to facebook page as page.I need to let the user automatically log in to facebook instead of asking user to log in.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to at least partially answer the question (you need **first** to login from a javascript-based client on the same browser+domain):

[Auto login with PHP facebook connect + JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665343/auto-login-with-php-facebook-connect-js)